# how to iterate through output of function in Python

Tags: python, function

I'm attempting to calculate the value based on a sequence of numbers, and find out how that value compares to if the sequence of numbers was randomly generated. To calculate the value of the sequence I have the random_lineup_value function, which works fine. To randomly generate 1000 sequences and calculate the value of each I have the random_lineup_values function.

However, the issue is that I can't compare the original value to these randomly generated values, because the output of the function is not subscriptable- or I cannot reference specific positions in this output. I'm trying to iterate through the ordered output of random_lineup_values until the initial stored value is equal to the number stored in the list of 1000 values. I've tried to return the output of random_lineup_value as a list, to use yield instead of return in the function, and to assign the output to a variable when I call the function and then try to iterate through positions of the list stored in the new variable, but none of these approaches work in Python. Any idea how to do this in Python?

```
    import random
    
    def lineup_value(order): 
         value = 0 
         for i in range(0,6): 
             if order[i] >= order[8]: 
                 value = value + 4 
             if order[i] >= order[7]: 
                 value = value + 4 
         for i in range(0,5): 
             if order[i] >= order[6]: 
                 value = value + 4 
         for i in [0, 1, 3]: 
             if order[i] >= order[5]: 
                 value = value + 4 
             if order[i] >= order[4]: 
                 value = value + 4 
         if order[3] >= order[2]: 
             value = value + 4 
         if order[1] >= order[2]: 
             value = value + 4 
         return value
    
    def random_lineup_values(order): 
        bootstrapped_values = [] 
        for j in range(0, 1000): 
            random.shuffle(order)                     
            bootstrapped_values.append(lineup_value(order)) 
        return list(bootstrapped_values.sort)
    
    random.seed(10)
    
    batting_order = [115, 101, 76, 125, 120, 135, 88, 94, 97]
    
    value = lineup_value(batting_order) 
    print(str(value) + ' is the value of the lineup') 
    sorted1 = random_lineup_values(batting_order) 
    print(sorted1)
        
    p = 0 
    number = sorted1[p] 
    while int(number) < int(value): 
        p = p + 1 print(p) 
    print(str((1000 - p) / 10) + ' percent of random lineup values would be better than the lineup')
```

Comment: Please fix your code formatting.

Comment: is this the error that you get:   `'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`   ..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't initially understand your question, but based on your code, I guessed that you wanted to run a list that contained a batting order through a function that determined that order's "value", and compare that to 1000 randomly generated different order's values. I made a couple of slight adjustments, and now it does what I believe you were trying to accomplish.

```
import random
    
def lineup_value(order): 
     value = 0 
     for i in range(0,6): 
         if order[i] >= order[8]: 
             value = value + 4 
         if order[i] >= order[7]: 
             value = value + 4 
     for i in range(0,5): 
         if order[i] >= order[6]: 
             value = value + 4 
     for i in [0, 1, 3]: 
         if order[i] >= order[5]: 
             value = value + 4 
         if order[i] >= order[4]: 
             value = value + 4 
     if order[3] >= order[2]: 
         value = value + 4 
     if order[1] >= order[2]: 
         value = value + 4 
     return value

def random_lineup_values(order, value): 
    bootstrapped_values = [] 
    newBootStrapped_values = []
    for j in range(0, 1000): 
        random.shuffle(order)                     
        bootstrapped_values.append(lineup_value(order))
    for j in range(0, 1000):
        if(bootstrapped_values[j] > value):
            newBootStrapped_values.append(bootstrapped_values[j])
            
    return list(sorted(newBootStrapped_values))

random.seed(10)

batting_order = [115, 101, 76, 125, 120, 135, 88, 94, 97]

value = lineup_value(batting_order) 
print(str(value) + ' is the value of the original lineup') 

sorted1 = random_lineup_values(batting_order, value)
print(str(len(sorted1)) + ' is the number of better value lineups out of 1000')
    
print(str(len(sorted1) / 10) + ' percent of random lineup values would be better than the lineup')
```

You'll notice that the biggest adjustment I made was adding an extra for loop in your random_lineup_values function. The first for loop gets the values of the 1000 random orders. The second for loop gets all of the values that are greater than the original order value (which should be 68 from the array that you provided) and appends them to a new list. The number of elements in that list out of 1000 times 100 (sorted1/10, to simplify) will get you the percentage of better batting orders. I did not change any logic for obtaining the batting order value, so if there is something wrong there, it will have to do with the logic of the lineup_value function, but as far as I know, it is functioning correctly. The output that I got after running this code was:

```
68 is the value of the original lineup
113 is the number of better value lineups out of 1000
11.3 percent of random lineup values would be better than the original lineup
```

Comment: Thank you! the addition of the second loop in the function fixes the issue and its running as I intended with your modifications

Answer (score 1):

The error is here:

```
x  = list(bootstrapped_values.sort)
```

by removing `.sort` it works.

```
x  = list(bootstrapped_values)
```

here is the function

```
def random_lineup_values(order): 
    bootstrapped_values = [] 
    for j in range(0, 1000): 
        random.shuffle(order) 
        bootstrapped_values.append(lineup_value(order)) 
        x  = list(bootstrapped_values) # <==  Exception has occurred: TypeError 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable
    return x
```

The error was this:
`Exception has occurred: TypeError 'builtin_function_or_method' object is not iterable`

Comment: thanks for your suggestion! I was still getting the error that the object isn't iterable with this method though, after I tried to define a sorted version of x with a new variable (I do need the output to be sorted for the purpose of what I was trying to do)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the issue you have is that you're only sorting and keeping track of the scores, not the `order` list that produced them. If you keep both things together in the same place, you can do what you want. (You also have a more glaring issue solved by [@D.L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7318120/d-l)'s answer, but I suspect that issue was caused by an attempted solution to the larger issue which I'm addressing.)

Try this, which builds and sorts a list of `(score, order)` 2-tuples.

```
def random_lineup_values(order): 
    bootstrapped_values = [] 
    for j in range(0, 1000): 
        random.shuffle(order)                     
        bootstrapped_values.append(lineup_value(order), order.copy())
    bootstrapped_values.sort()
    return bootstrapped_values
```

Note that I'm adding a `copy()` of the `order` list in the tuple because the shuffling to build new orders happens in place. This may also mean you'll want to copy the original lineup too at the start of the function, so you don't destroy the order of the list you're passed as an argument (but I don't fully understand the calling code, so I'm not sure if you care about that or not).